# Laravel Ldaprecord - display retrieved data from Active Directory in blade

Tags: php, laravel, active-directory, ldap

When I retrieve data from Active Directory like:

```
 $users = User::whereStartsWith('cn', $request->search)
        ->limit(3)
        ->get();
```

I retrieve an collection which looks like this:

```
    LdapRecord\Models\Collection {#350 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => LdapRecord\Models\ActiveDirectory\User {#353 ▼
      #passwordAttribute: "unicodepwd"
      #passwordHashMethod: "encode"
      #dates: array:7 [▶]
      #defaultDates: array:3 [▶]
      #sidKey: "objectsid"
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      +wasRecentlyRenamed: false
      #dn: "CN=DOE John,DC=my,DC=domain"
      #in: null
      #connection: null
      #guidKey: "objectguid"
      #modifications: []
      #original: array:95 [▶]
      #attributes: array:95 [▶]
      #casts: []
      #appends: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
    }
    1 => LdapRecord\Models\ActiveDirectory\User {#354 ▼
      #passwordAttribute: "unicodepwd"
      #passwordHashMethod: "encode"
      #dates: array:7 [▶]
      #defaultDates: array:3 [▶]
      #sidKey: "objectsid"
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      +wasRecentlyRenamed: false
      #dn: "CN=SMITH Jan,DC=my,DC=domain"
      #in: null
      #connection: null
      #guidKey: "objectguid"
      #modifications: []
      #original: array:94 [▶]
      #attributes: array:94 [▶]
      #casts: []
      #appends: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
    }
    2 => LdapRecord\Models\ActiveDirectory\User {#357 ▼
      #passwordAttribute: "unicodepwd"
      #passwordHashMethod: "encode"
      #dates: array:7 [▶]
      #defaultDates: array:3 [▶]
      #sidKey: "objectsid"
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      +wasRecentlyRenamed: false
      #dn: "CN=LORD Coeh,DC=my,DC=domain"
      #in: null
      #connection: null
      #guidKey: "objectguid"
      #modifications: []
      #original: array:66 [▶]
      #attributes: array:66 [▶]
      #casts: []
      #appends: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
    }
  ]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```

Inside this collection, under protected property called `#original`(which is also an array), there are fields like `sAMAccountName`, `dc`, `mail` etc (there are different amount depends of user).

I can't display it in blade using `foreach` like:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
  <tr>
      <td>{{ $user->cn }}</td>
      <td>{{ $user->samaccountname }}</td>
      <td>{{ $user->mail }}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Because I got an error:

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

How to print elements, which are sewn inside collection?

Comment: One of those properties `->cn`, `->samaccountname` or `->mail` is an array, and you can't display an array via `{{ }}`; you need to figure out which property is causing that error, and adjust your code to something like `@foreach($user->cn as $cn)`, then you can print `$cn` via `{{ $cn }}` (or `$samaccountname`, or `$mail`, etc., whichever property is causing that)

Comment: Is it possible to simplify that? It's working when I perform `foreach` on each field like `cn`,`samaccountname`, `mail`.

Comment: You can `implode()` the arrays to a single comma-separated string, like `{{ implode($user->cn, ', ') }}`, but "simplify" is a vague word here; how do you want to simplify this? Regardless of what you do, just remember that `{{ }}` doesn't play well with arrays; you need to convert the array to something that can be printed with `{{ }}`, like a string, etc.

Answer (score 0):

One of the properties are an array and must be imploded to a String before it can be used by the html processor `{{ }}`.

The following code checks if the property is an array, then it performs the implode function, otherwise it returns the original value of property.

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
  <tr>
      <td>{{ (is_array($user->cn)) ? implode($user->cn) : $user->cn }}</td>
      <td>{{ (is_array($user->samaccountname)) ? implode($user->samaccountname) : $user->samaccountname }}</td>
      <td>{{ (is_array($user->mail)) ? implode($user->mail) : $user->mail }}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```